# grep -v or grep --invert-match doesn't work on Big Sur

Tags: terminal, big-sur

The command I am running is:

```
du -h -d 1 | grep -v "not permitted"
```

or

```
du -h -d 1 | grep --invert-match "not permitted"
```

This should show every line except those matching "not permitted", but instead it acts as if the `-v` or `--invert-match` wasn't there and just shows the lines matching "not permitted".

`man grep` tells me that it should be supported and working.

Am I missing something, or is it broken? I am currently at Big Sur 11.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` is not broken per-se in **macOS Big Sur**.

The output you are seeing is `stderr` output from the `du`*command* and it is a separate *stream* from `stdout` that is being being piped to `grep`.

Use `du -h -d 1 2>/dev/null` instead, or use `du -h -d 1 2>&1 | grep -v 'not permitted'`, however, I'd use the former instead in this particular use case.

Have a look at [Standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) as a reference on **standard input** (`stdin`), **standard output** (`stdout`) and **standard error** (`stderr`).

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't realised those were going to stderr. That said, shouldn't my original command still be showing the non-matches from stdout?

Comment: Looks like it's something weird with piping the output of `du` - if there are no "not permitted" results, piping to `grep` works as expected. If there are "not permitted" results, piping to `grep` only shows the "not permitted" results, even without `-v`. Even `du -h -d 1 | more` only shows the "not permitted" results if there are any but works correctly if there aren't any!

Comment: Yes, that's because, just like this answer says, you are `grep`ping stdout, but errors are obviously written to stderr, that's what it's there for.

Comment: But the non-error results should still go to stdout. Why do those results disappear if there are *any* stderr results when piping?